# hector_slam, read sensors over Ethernet?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, hector-slam, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if it is possible to read the Hokuyo and IMU data via Ethernet rather than through the USB ports?

My current desire is to have the sensors attached to a raspberry pi/other interface and transmit the sensor data via wifi to the hector_slam host computer.

I appreciate any thoughts here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56210/hector_slam,-read-sensors-over-ethernet?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure, you just need to get them into an ethernet interface from somewhere. You obviously can't connect the USB ports to an ethernet cable (unless the sensor provides data via ethernet like the newest Hokuyo or some Sicks).

The usual option would to use be mini-computers like a gumstix or your rapberry pi and get the laser data via USB from there to transmit it via ethernet. I'm not sure if you mean to transfer raw binary data via wifi and collect it there, which would require extra software.

The easiest would be to run ROS on the embedded system and just run the ROS drivers from there. Then you can run everything like you would normally do.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0